# Howto deploy latest netplan main on 20.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, netplan

Well, title says mostly all. I have a problem with netplan as it is distributed with current 20.04.3 (#102) and even #103 which is in proposed is not good enough.
New "ignore-carrier" option which is kind of new seems to fit the bill, but it is not obvious to me how to deploy current neplan.io "main".

Help ?

Comment: You will get better help if you ask about the actual problem you are encountering that leads you to believe that "ignore-carrier" is the best solution. There might be other solutions.

Comment: For your specific question "*How to get Netplan 103 on 20.04*," LTS releases like 20.04 are generally frozen and get only security patches after release. Bolting a newer version is rarely a good idea. HOWEVER, you're in luck: Netplan 103 has been backported to 20.04; it's currently in testing (focal-proposed). If testing goes well, your system should see the upgrade in perhaps a week or two. There's no magic: An ordinary `sudo apt update`/`sudo apt upgrade` will pick it up when it emerges from testing.

Comment: Thanks, I've already updated to #103 using the proposed distro. The bit I'm looking for did not cut for that distro. I'm trying to fit several network configs into netplan + networkd, but it seems networkd-dispatcher is dying on startup because of a timeout, apparently because some of my interfaces do not have carrier.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted here (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2464731&p=14047808#post14047808) all you need is some dependencies.
Then make, make install.

The dependencies (for me) where glib-2.0 gio-2.0 libyaml-dev libglib2.0-dev libsystemd-dev pandoc.
Install installed the .so in /lib which was not picked by ldd (preferred /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetplan.so.0.0 from the standard package). After fixing that, it worked.

On the other hand, networkd-dispatcher still dies with timeout. All interaces now are configured or unmanaged (no more "configuring")

Comment: Just FYI if you happen to land here looking for my original problem, in my setup the standard 90 seconds start up time was not enough for networkd-dispatcher, because I was bringing up pppoe with a carrier-up script and systemd was waiting for the whole thing to finish first run. Bumped TimeoutStartSec to 180 and all is good now.